# Content type not showing in the "New" document button when displaying managed metadata column on list

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, list-view, managed-metadata

I am currently developing a document library on SharePoint Online.

However whenever I tried to show a managed metadata column on list, the content type choices in the "New" document button on tool bar became weird. It no longer showed the content types I defined, instead it showed the default Office options (Word documents, Excel workbook, PowerPoint Presentation, and OneNote notebook).

However, when I removed the managed metadata column from the list, content types in the "New" button displayed correctly..

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Terence, I can't offer you a fix, but I can say I am seeing similar behavior. I've a document library which I've configured to only contain a Document Set content type I created. The behavior is intermittent. Sometimes the Add button shows the Document Set content type, sometimes it shows the default Office ones you are seeing. It's almost as if the page doesn't load correctly on occasions. My Content Type does not use Managed Metadata, and still suffers from the issue.

Comment: I just noticed same exact issue happening. Just to clarify that new in the ribbon still works fine, but toolbar new button is not showing content types as described above.
Is there a work around for this? Is this a bug? Platform: Sharepoint Office 365.

Comment: The workaround I come up with right now is using CSS to hide that "New" button on toolbar...At least it won't make me embarrassing when I am in presentation...

Comment: I have the same problem and i have now registered a support ticket at MS. I will get back to you when they come up with a solution/cause of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be because you are having Metadata columns defined in the Content Type. As of this moment that is not working as expected in SharePoint Online.